# Does HttpRequest.setClientCertificateName always send a certificate?

Tags: httprequest, http, certificates

We are trying to use certificates to authenticate the client (Sales Force) calling our back-end system. However, as far as we can see, SalesForce is not sending any certificate.

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); 
req.setClientCertificateName('foo');
req.setEndpoint('http://requestb.in/bar');
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Accept', '*/*');
HTTPResponse res;
try {   
    Http http = new Http(); 
    res = http.send(req);
    if (res.getStatusCode() == 200)
        system.debug(res.getBody());
    else
      result = 'Error: ' + res.getStatusCode();
} catch(Exception e) {
    system.debug('HTTP Failed: ' + e.getMessage());
}
```

The debug output is (HTTP Status 200):

```
ok
```

Our request bin shows no certificate in the headers:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Sfdc-Stack-Depth: 1
Via: 1.1 vegur
Total-Route-Time: 0
Host: requestb.in
Pragma: no-cache
X-Request-Id: 317blah7-8207-485b-8e05-67c33ae3d964
Connect-Time: 1
User-Agent: SFDC-Callout/35.0
Accept: */*
Connection: close
```

Is this an issue on the client (Apex Code) or does our Server need to request the certificate?

Answer (score 1):

First of all certificates are used only when your using https endpoint. In your case you are using http endpoint.
What kind of identification you want to do here.
Is is one way ssl or two way SSL. If one way SSL is there where back-end system is configured with certificate then you don't have to do anything just put https as endpoint and make sure that certificate used by back-end system is signed by Certificate Authority to which salesforce trusts.

Here is the link if you want to check CA list which salesforce accepts/trusts:
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Outbound_Messaging_SSL_CA_Certificates#addtrustclass1ca
If you face any issues here please update. I am happy to assist.

Comment: The question is about client- side certificates i.e. The client(salesforce) proving its identity to the server. The other way around is working fine. We are indeed using https but getting a 403 but I take your point: I need an HTTPS paste bin! Thanks!

Comment: Could not find an HTTPS request bin but I must query this: Surely I can do client authentication with certificate via HTTP? HTTPS is only for ensuring the identity of the *server* IMO...